# how to save changes in an existing trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trriger in a table, but I need to add a new line of code, and when I click the save button, I am prompted to save a .sql file,I save it but the changes are not saved in the trigger.

I am using SQL Server 2014 express.

So I would like to know how can I save the changes in my existing trigger.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I hope you don't have any scalar values in your trigger. Are you declaring variables in your trigger? If so, you are likely going to have issues because the code may not be able to handle multiple row operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you made your changes in Trigger, you then have to Press **F5**.  Then the Trigger code compiles.  If SQL Compiled it successfully it will be saved, otherwise it throw error message to you.

So next time when you open trigger again, you are able to see your updated Trigger code.

Comment: Of course I have to point out that you should save it as a SQl script and keep it in your source control like any other code. No change should ever be made to a database object that is not scripted out.

Comment: @HLGEM:- right, definitely OP somewhere have to sql script to maintain version control.